# Passing array of struct from C# to C++ using C++/CLI wrapper

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, c++-cli, marshalling

I am working in a project where we need to optimize a C# code, so I am translating the code to C++ and to do so, I am using a C++/CLI wrapper which works as a bridge between managed C# and unmanaged C++. I am trying to communicate both but it doesn't work since I am quite new with this topic. I have been looking and searching a lot but remains the same.

I wanted to have the same array of structs that I have in C# in the native C++, this is the main goal to achive.

My C# code "ConsoleApp1" is the following:

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        // Struct definition
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
        public struct MyStruct
        {
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
            public int a;

            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
            public int b;

            public MyStruct(int a, int b)
            {
                this.a = a;
                this.b = b;
            }
        };

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            UnmanagedWrap.Class1 test = new UnmanagedWrap.Class1();

            // Instantiating struct and initializing
            MyStruct str1 = new MyStruct(4, 5);
            MyStruct str2 = new MyStruct(6, 7);

            // Array of structs
            MyStruct[] MyArray = new MyStruct[] { str1, str2 };

            // Calling C++/CLI method passing the struct
            test.Foo(MyArray, MyArray.GetLength);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Then my C++/CLI wrapper called UnmanagedWrap:

```
namespace UnmanagedWrap {

    public ref class Class1
    {
    public:

        // pointer to the Unmanaged class
        Unmanaged * pu;  

        // the constructor will allocate the pointer pu
        Class1() : pu(new Unmanaged()) {};      

        void Foo(array<MyStruct^>^ configObject, int ArrayLength) {

            // Allocates memory from the unmanaged memory of the process by using the specified number of bytes.
            // Between brackets is the required number of bytes in memory.
            IntPtr ptr = Marshal::AllocHGlobal(Marshal::SizeOf(configObject));

            // Marshals data from a managed object to an unmanaged block of memory. 
            // ptr is a pointer to an unmanaged block of memory, which must be allocated before this method is called.
            Marshal::StructureToPtr(configObject, ptr, false);

            pu->Foo(ptr);
        };
    };

    public ref struct MyStruct {
        int a;
        int b;
    };
}
```

And my unmanaged C++ Unmanaged.h:

```
#pragma once
class Unmanaged
{
public:

    struct MyUnmanagedStruct {
        int var1, var2;
    };

    void Foo(MyUnmanagedStruct* d);
};
```

And Unmanaged.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Unmanaged.h"

void Unmanaged::Foo(MyUnmanagedStruct* ustr) {
    int x = ustr->var1;
    int y = ustr->var1;
}
```

This procedure doesn't work because of type mismatch in the calling function from C++/CLI to C++, but I don't know how to do it the right way even though I looked for it a lot.

Comment: Delete the C# declaration of the struct, it should use the declaration provided by the C++/CLI assembly.  Change it to public value struct {} to make it a struct instead of class type.  How the caller, passing an array, should call a C++ function that can only modify a single element of the array is not otherwise obvious.

Comment: Since you're writing both sides of the code, you can pass .net types and let the C++/CLI handle the conversion of String^ to LPWStr, if that is needed to communicate with some lower level API.